# Can I create real-time push notifications in C# desktop application?

Tags: c#, push-notification, client-server

I want to create an application which will be multiple client server application. All the computers are connected via the LAN. I want to generate a push notification on the admin computer when a client makes a query request. The notification should be real-time without loading the dashboard.

Comment: Your question is pretty light on details.  What are you planning to use, WPF?

Comment: I'm using winforms

Answer (score 0):

If you are up for rolling your own, you could potentially look into [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).  Its a free open source robust messaging system that would allow you to publish message to an exchange from the admin computer.  Then the clients would subscribe to get the notifications/messages.

They have good [getting started tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) over on the main website.  In particular, you might want to look at the [Publish/Subscribe tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html)

You can use nuget to pick up the offical RabbitMQ C# library. Although, once you have your exchange & queues setup inside RabbitMQ you can even send the messages to the queue from anywhere using HTTP POST messages if you wish.

However, you would need to setup RabbitMQ on a server somewhere which might be a deal breaker if you havent got access to a server to install rabbitMQ on. It would need to sit there in the background to processing the messages for you.

That my 2 pence worth.